# What do PorterDuff source and destination refer to when drawing on canvas?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-canvas

I've been trying to figure this out all night, but answers found on Google relate to very specific problems regarding Android's canvas and I haven't found any 101 explanations on this topic. Even Android documentation uses bitmaps instead of drawing shapes.

Specific problem:

I need to draw an oval and a path on canvas. And according to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html) colour source out with one colour, destination out another colour and overlapping area, either source in or destination in, a third colour. I'm trying to do all this in an offscreen canvas. but problems arise with some of the steps above and get worse when trying to combine them in any way.

- Code -

  ```
      Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.CreateBitmap (720, 720, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
      Canvas c = new Canvas (bmp);

      Paint paint = new Paint ();
      paint.SetARGB (255, 255, 0, 0);
      c.DrawOval (200, 200, 520, 520, paint); //assumed destination

      paint.SetARGB (255, 0, 0, 255);
      paint.SetXfermode (new PorterDuffXfermode (PorterDuff.Mode.*)); //replace mode here
      paint.SetStyle (Paint.Style.Fill);

      Path path = new Path ();
      path.MoveTo (c.Width / 2f, c.Height / 2f);

      foreach (var m in measurements) {
          //calculations

          float x = xCalculatedValue
          float y = yCalculatedValue

          path.LineTo (x, y);
      }

      path.LineTo (c.Width / 2f, c.Height / 2f);

      c.DrawPath (path, paint); //assumed source
  ```
- Source out -

This instead draws what XOR is supposed to draw.

- Destination out -

This works as expected.

- Source in -

This draws what source atop should.

- Destination in -

This draws what destination should.

More general question:

What do source and destination refer to in this context? Intuitively I would assume that destination is the current state of the canvas bitmap and source is the matrix added by canvas.Draw* and Paint PortedDuff.Mode. But that doesn't seem to be the case.

**EDIT:** This is basically the effect I'm after, where the "star" is a dynamic path. Coloured three different colours depending on overlap.

[Crude drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaUsn.jpg)

**EDIT 2:** York Shen did a great job answering the actual question. But for anyone wanting to get a similar effect here's the final code.

```
Bitmap DrawGraphBitmapOffscreen ()
{
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.CreateBitmap (720, 720, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas (bmp);

    // Replace with calculated path
    Path path = new Path ();
    path.MoveTo (c.Width / 2f, c.Height / 2f);
    path.LineTo (263, 288);
    path.LineTo (236, 202);
    path.LineTo (312, 249);
    path.LineTo (331, 162);
    path.LineTo (374, 240);
    path.LineTo (434, 174);
    path.LineTo (431, 263);
    path.LineTo (517, 236);
    path.LineTo (470, 312);
    path.LineTo (557, 331);
    path.LineTo (479, 374);
    path.LineTo (545, 434);
    path.LineTo (456, 431);
    path.LineTo (483, 517);
    path.LineTo (407, 470);
    path.LineTo (388, 557);
    path.LineTo (345, 479);
    path.LineTo (285, 545);
    path.LineTo (288, 456);
    path.LineTo (202, 483);
    path.LineTo (249, 407);
    path.LineTo (162, 388);
    path.LineTo (240, 345);
    path.LineTo (174, 285);
    path.LineTo (263, 288);
    path.Close ();

    Paint paint = new Paint ();

    paint.SetARGB (255, 255, 0, 0);
    paint.SetStyle (Paint.Style.Fill);

    c.DrawPath (path, paint);

    paint.SetARGB (255, 0, 0, 255);
    paint.SetXfermode (new PorterDuffXfermode (PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn));

    c.DrawOval (200, 200, 520, 520, paint);

    paint.SetARGB (255, 255, 255, 255);
    paint.SetXfermode (new PorterDuffXfermode (PorterDuff.Mode.DstOver));

    c.DrawOval (200, 200, 520, 520, paint);

    return bmp;
}
```

Comment: What is the effect you want, draw an oval and a path on canvas? Why you use `PorterDuffXfermode`? If you just need to draw an oval and a path, there is no need to use `PorterDuffX`.

Comment: I added an image to explain what I'm trying to do. I'm not sure alpha compositing is the best solution, but it's the only one that came to mind. And more than an actual solution to the problem, I'd like to understand what source and destination refer to in the context of drawing things one after another on a canvas.

Comment: So you want draw an oval and a polygon, then use `PorterDuffXfermode` to achieve the effect in the picture you have post?

Comment: That's the problem though. As I explained, the modes are are not behaving as I would expect them to based on the documentation. I think the problem is the fact that I don't understand what the source and destination refer to. Do you mind giving a quick explanation? Or a piece of code to achieve the result in the image?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What do PorterDuff source and destination refer to when drawing on canvas?

After some in-depth study, I write a few demo to explain this deeply. To help you understand what is source and destination refer to.

**First, look at the following code** :

```
protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    base.OnDraw(canvas);

    Paint paint = new Paint();

    //Set the background color
    canvas.DrawARGB(255, 139, 197, 186);

    int canvasWidth = canvas.Width;
    int r = canvasWidth / 3;

    //Draw a yellow circle
    paint.Color = Color.Yellow;
    canvas.DrawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

    //Draw a blue rectangle
    paint.Color = Color.Blue;
    canvas.DrawRect(r, r, r * 2.7f, r * 2.7f, paint);
}
```

I override the `OnDraw` method, set a green background, then draw a yellow circle and a blue rectangle, effect :

[image]

Above is the normal procedure when we draw a `Canvas`, I didn't use any `PorterDuffXfermode`,let's analyse its process :

- First, we call `canvas.DrawARGB(255, 139, 197, 186)` method  draw the whole `Canvas` with a single color, every pixels in this canvas has the same `ARGB` value : `(255, 139, 197, 186)`. Since the alpha value in `ARGB` is 255 instead of 0, so every pixels is opaque.
- Second, when we execute `canvas.DrawCircle(r, r, r, paint)`  method, Android will draw a yellow circle at the position you have defined. All pixels which ARGB value is `(255,139,197,186)` in this circle will be replaced with yellow pixels.
  **The yellow pixels is source and the pixels which ARGB value is `(255,139,197,186)` is destination.** I will explain later.
- Third, after execute the `canvas.DrawRect(r, r, r * 2.7f, r * 2.7f, paint)` method, Android will draw a blue rectangle, all pixels in this rectangle is blue, and these blue pixels will replac other pixels in the same position. So the blue rectangle can be draw on `Canvas`.

**Second, I use a mode of `Xfermode`, `PorterDuff.Mode.Clear` :**

```
 protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.OnDraw(canvas);

        Paint paint = new Paint();

        //Set the background color
        canvas.DrawARGB(255, 139, 197, 186);

        int canvasWidth = canvas.Width;
        int r = canvasWidth / 3;

        //Draw a yellow circle
        paint.Color = Color.Yellow;
        canvas.DrawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

        //Use Clear as PorterDuffXfermode to draw a blue rectangle
        paint.SetXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.Clear));

        paint.Color = Color.Blue;
        canvas.DrawRect(r, r, r * 2.7f, r * 2.7f, paint);

        paint.SetXfermode(null);
        this.SetLayerType(LayerType.Software, null);

        //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        //I found that PorterDuff.Mode.Clear doesn't work with hardware acceleration, so you have add this code
  }
```

Effect :

[image]

Let's analyse its process :

- First, we call `canvas.DrawARGB(255, 139, 197, 186)` method to draw the whole `Canvas` as a single color, every pixels is opaque.
- Second, we call `canvas.DrawCircle(r, r, r, paint)` method to draw a yellow
  circle in `Canvas`.
- Third, execute `paint.SetXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.Clear))`, set the paint `PorterDuff` model to `Clear`.
- Forth, call `canvas.DrawRect(r, r, r * 2.7f, r * 2.7f, paint)` to draw a blue rectangle, and finally it shows a white rectangle.

**Why it display a white rectangle**? Usually, when we call `canvas.DrawXXX()` method we will pass a `Paint` parameter, when Android execute draw method it will check whether the paint has a `Xfermode` mode. If not, then the graphics will directly covers the pixels that in `Canvas` at the same position. Otherwise, it will update the pixels in `Canvas` according to the `Xfermode` mode.

In my example, when execute `canvas.DrawCirlce()` method, `Paint` didn't has a `Xfermode` model, so the yellow circle directly cover the pixels in `Canvas`. But when we call `canvas.DrawRect()` to draw a rectangle, `Paint` has a `Xfermode` value `PorterDuff.Mode.Clear`. **Then Android will draw a rectangle in memory, the pixels in this rectangle has a name : Source**. **The rectangle in memory has a corresponding rectangle in `Canvas`, the corresponding rectangle is called :
destination .**

The value of the `ARGB` of the source pixel and the value of the `ARGB` of the destination pixel are calculated according to the rules defined by `Xfermode`, it will calculate the final ARGB value.  Then update the `ARGB` value of the target pixel with the final `ARGB` value.

In my example, the `Xfermode` is `PorterDuff.Mode.Clear`, it require destination pixels `ARGB` becomes `(0,0,0,0)`, that means it is transparent. So we use `canvas.DrawRect()` method draw a transparent rectangle in `Canvas`, since `Activity` itself has a white background color, so it will show an white rectangle.

**EDIT :**

To implement the feature you post in the picture, I write a demo :

```
protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    base.OnDraw(canvas);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.SetARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);
    RectF oval2 = new RectF(60, 100, 300, 200);
    canvas.DrawOval(oval2, paint);

    paint.SetXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.*));

    Path path = new Path();
    paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Fill);
    paint.SetARGB(255, 0, 0, 255);

    path.MoveTo(180, 50);
    path.LineTo(95, 240);
    path.LineTo(255, 240);
    path.Close();

    this.SetLayerType(LayerType.Software, null);
    canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
    paint.SetXfermode(null);
}
```

When use different `Xfermode`, their effect :

[Xor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELJH6.png), [SrcOut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpLeG.png), [Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhxRJ.png), [Lighten](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx8pc.png), [Darken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzv3c.png), [Add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcOTf.png).

As you can see, you could use different color and  different `Xfermode` to achieve your effect.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you so much. "Then Android will draw a rectangle in memory, the pixels in this rectangle has a name : Source. The rectangle in memory has a corresponding rectangle in Canvas, the corresponding rectangle is called : destination ." This is exactly what I was after. I thought destination was the entire canvas.

Comment: @York Shen if possible can you pease share your mail